# How does LINQ-To-SQL prevent SQL-Injections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-injection

I'm currently doing a project with C# and LINQ-TO-SQL. This project has security as a high priority, so obviously I want to prevent SQL-Injections. I googled on the matter, but it's not turning up anything useful. 
Microsoft's own FAQ told me that Injections would be no problem, because of the way LINQ handles parameters, however seeing the code LINQ produces in a debugger and having read a bit about how LINQ-To-SQL just builds to SQL I'm not sure how this applies.

Does anyone have any literature/linkage that deals with this matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq to SQL automatically uses [SQLParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). User input is turned into parameter values instead of simply being a concatenated string (which is what allows for SQL injections). This happens serverside, IIRC, so you might just be seeing the client side code. If you want a bit more background and info, you can read [the information here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34653).

Comment: Okay, Page 2 of the article cleared my question. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty simple, really - the translation never injects variables without parameterising them; so:

```
var orders = from ord in ctx.Orders
             where ord.CustomerName = name
             select ord;
```

will become:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE [CustomerName] = @p0
```

where `p0` is a parameter with value taken from your captured `name`

nothing more, nothing less. But this avoids injection attacks. Contrast to an ***incorrect*** accidental:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE [CustomerName] = '" + name + "'";
```

which introduces huge risks. You can of course parameterise the above correctly, too:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE [CustomerName] = @name";
```

(and add a parameter `@name` with value from `name`)

Comment: How so? Let's say I have an input field containing a String. Somebody enters ";Drop Database" or something similar. This evaluates to `SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE [CustomerId] = ;Drop Database`. Don't I have a problem then?

Comment: @fk2 `@p0` ***is a parameter***; it is never evaluated as TSQL; it can be any string content, without any risk

Comment: @fk2 no it does not evaluate to that, sql parameters are not substituted for their values to build up a sql string to execute. parameters contain data and are not executed as sql.

Comment: @fk2 , kinda of a blast from the past , but what you said would be evaluated like `SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE [CustomerId] = ";Drop Database"` . If the is no `CUstomerId` with id `;Drop Database` , it will return an empty select..

Answer (score 1):

It uses parmeterized queries. http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34653/1954